# Drupal php query not working with certain words

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am writing a custom search module for Drupal 6. I have this php query here that grabs the search term and checks the DB for a 'like' term.

For some reason the query fails with certain words like "benchmarking"

```
$search_array_events_query_thing= db_query('SELECT title, url, description  FROM {my_table} 
WHERE keywords LIKE  "%'.$keys.'%" AND description <> ""
ORDER BY weight DESC');
```

$keys = to the user's search term.

When I run the query via phpMyAdmin it works just fine.

Comment: is it `"benchmarking"` or `benchmarking` with out the double quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$search_array_events_query_thing= db_query("SELECT title, url, description  
FROM {my_table} 
WHERE keywords LIKE  '%".$keys."%' AND description <> ''
ORDER BY weight DESC");
```

Comment: Can you explain ? (Flagged as low quality)